# The mystery of the jumps of functions with the prescribed jumps: Eisenstein series and hidden symmetries(?)

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, measure-theory, modular-forms, langlands-conjectures

Say that a function $f(t)$ “changes only by jumps” if $f(t) + \text{const} = C ∑_k j_k θ(t-t_k)$ for a certain constant $C$.  Here $θ(t)$ is the [Heaviside
step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) which has a jump 1 at $t=0$ (it is 0 for $t<0$ and 1 for $t≥0$), and $f(t)$ has jumps $j_k$ at points $t_k$.  (The reason for using
a coefficient $C$ is shown below; in the simplest cases $C=1$.)

Obviously, this holds for piecewise-constant functions with finitely many jumps: the sum is finite, and it indeed has jumps $j_k/C$ at
points $t_k$, with $C=1$.  This may be restated as: “the actual jumps” of the sum coincide with “the prescribed jumps” $j_k$.  The same
happens when the series converges absolutely (in particular, the sum is right- and left-continuous).

In general, without the condition of absolute convergence “everything may happen”.  However, what I would never expect is an example
of “a reasonable function” $f(t)$ for which the identity above holds with $C=½$.  In other words:
the actual jumps of the sum are twice the prescribed jumps.

I discovered such an example when examining plots of certain Fourier series appearing¹⁾ in the Artin case of the Langlands program.
**Question:** are there other interesting cases when $C≠1$?  Or other similar “pathologies”?

> ¹⁾ In fact, me considering this case was a result of misunderstanding on my part.  (So I do not know whether this example is in the
> scope of the “real” Langlands program.)  See [my notes; search for all places mentioning Eisenstein](http://ilyaz.org/papers/Reciprocity_Langlands/).

This essentially ends my question.  However, since the claim above about C=½ seems so incredible, below I provide the details of my
example. — And this takes **quite some space** (sorry)!

> (An impatient reader may want to jump to the picture below showing plots of two functions with “reasonably defined” jumps at *disjoint* subsets of ℚ.)

#### Restating in terms of derivative

By the way: one can restate the question in terms of $\operatorname{d}f=f'(t)\operatorname{d}t$ — and then instead of $f$ “changing only by jumps” it is about
“atomic” generalized functions, which are sums of shifts of atomic δ-measures.  The advantage of this approach is that in our
example $\operatorname{d}f$ is actually a boundary value of a modular 1-form, hence is a modular-invariant 1-form on ℝℙ¹.

My gut feeling is that appearance of “extra” coefficient 2 is due to “effects of a certain ‘hidden symmetry’”.  One can notice that
in our example $\operatorname{d}f$ has not only the modular symmetries, but also the “functional equation” symmetry $t ↦ -1/13t$.  (It is not modular
since there is no matrix in GL₂ℚ with determinant ±1 which matches this projective transformation.)  Moreover, this symmetry
*exchanges* differentials of two parts of $f$ considered below.

However, I cannot see how this symmetry may be explicitly related to the “extra” coefficient 2.  I suspect a presence of “yet
another discrete symmetry”…

### Details of the example

The *prescribed* jumps are going to be $±1/Q$ at every (irreducible) rational $P/Q$.  To explain the signs, recall that when working with
modular forms and modular symbols²⁾, the simplest examples are Eisenstein series.  At a real value $t$ of the argument, they may be
written as $f(t) ≔ ∑_{r=0}^t J(r)$, with the summation running over rational numbers, and $J(P/Q)$ a certain function on ℚ.  (Here and
below for simplicity we take $t≥0$.  Of course, there is an immediate generalization for $t<0$.)

> ²⁾ … which are antiderivatives of modular forms.  These may be a little bit easier to work with than “proper” modular forms; indeed
> the latter ones are defined on $\{\operatorname{Im} z > 0\}$ and are too singular near ℝ; hence their restrictions to ℝ are “only” generalized
> functions.  On the other hand, taking the antiderivative “mollifies” singularities, hence the restrictions of the antiderivative
> may be  “smooth enough” to “almost” have values at points.  (At least, in the cases we consider here they have left and right
> limits.)
>
> Note that $f'(t)$ is “atomic”, i.e., a sum of shifts $J(r)δ(t-r)$ of δ-functions at $r∈ℚ$.  Compare to the reformulation above.

Obviously: if the sum converges absolutely, then $f(t)$ has right and left limits, and its jump at $t=r$ is $J(r)$.  For example, this
happens if $J(P/Q)=B(P/Q)/Q^s$ with $s>2$ and $B(r)$ bounded (for this formula to make sense, assume $P$ and $Q$ coprime and $Q>0$).  However, in
many cases³⁾ the sum can be assigned a “reasonable” sense even if there is no absolute convergence.  For example, one can sum first
over rationals with denominator 1, then with 2, etc. — since this specifies an order of summation, one can ask whether the series
converges or not.

> ³⁾ For example, the sum described above is an analytic function of $s∈C$ for $\operatorname{Re}s>2$.  It may have an analytic continuation to a
> larger region in ℂ.  (Note that for many [“summation methods”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Theorems_on_methods_for_summing_divergent_series) the result of summation remains an analytic function of $s$.
> Using a “stronger” summation method than “taking lim of partial sums” may extend the region of convergence.  In other words,
> such a summation method would “expose a part of the analytic continuation of the sum”.)

Moreover, convergence means that in the sum, positive $J(r)$ “mostly compensate” negative $J(r)$: two sums over positives/negatives
diverge, but taken together two speeds of divergence cancel each other.  For example, if for fixed $Q$ one assigns $B(P/Q)$ randomly
to be ±1 or 0 so that the frequency of $+1$ is the same as the frequency of $-1$, then $B(r)$ with the denominator $Q$ contribute (roughly
speaking) $O(\sqrt Q)/Q^s$ into the sum.  Hence the sum converges (almost surely) if $s>1$.  (Such questions of probabilistic convergence are
addressed by [“Kolmogorov’s 2-series criterion”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_Two-Series_Theorem).)

In fact, if the cancellation in⁴⁾ $S(t,Q) ≔ ∑_{P=0}^{⌊tQ⌋} B(P/Q)$ is even stronger than for random $B$, then the sum may converge for $s=1$.
And this is what happens for “[Eisenstein series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series) of weight 2 with quadratic character”.

> ⁴⁾ I abuse notations since the sum must skip $P$ not coprime with $Q$.

#### Quadratic Eisenstein series of weight 2

For example, in the case when the conductor $c≡₄1$ is ±prime, $B(P/Q)$ is the Legendre “quadratic residue” symbol⁵⁾ $ℒ(Q \operatorname{mod} c)$ unless
$c|Q$, otherwise $B(P/Q) = ℒ(P \operatorname{mod} c) \sqrt c$ (here we again assume that $P$,$Q$ are coprime, and $Q>0$).

> ⁵⁾ Abuse of notation: for negative $c$, we should take the Kronecker symbol, not the Legendre one.  So in the example we take $c>0$.

This breaks the series into two parts (for $c∤Q$ and $c|Q$).  Here are the plots of the partial sums⁶⁾ of these parts with $Q≤l$ (and $Q≤cl$ for the second part) with
$l=1000$, $c=13$ over their period:

[image: Partial sums of two parts up to 1000th term]

> ⁶⁾ In fact, I cheated a bit: the first partial sum is taken with a certain regularization.  (Details below.)

One can see that the blue plot has the prescribed jumps at $P/Q$ with $13|Q$, and the red one behaves likewise with $13∤Q$.  However,
*otherwise* the plots more or less coincide!

CONCLUSION: when $l→∞$, two parts of the sum coincide.  Hence *every* part would have the jumps of *both* types.  And the sum of these
two parts would have *twice* the prescribed jumps!  This finishes our example of how $C$ may be equal to ½.

(Well, the argument above only *describes* what happens.  The details and proofs are in [the paper linked to above](http://ilyaz.org/papers/Reciprocity_Langlands/).  However, this
is the case when having a proof does not bring any satisfaction — I still have no clue *why* this phenomenon appears…)

#### The regularization

For completeness, I discuss a minor cheating used above.

Without regularization, the partial sum over $Q≤1000$ with $13∤Q$ would acquire a “parasitic” linear term $M_{1000}·t$ with $M_{1000}≈0.748$.
When increasing the limit of summation $l$, *on average* $M_l→0$.  (E.g., this happens with [“Cesàro summation”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation) in $Q$ instead of a
“rigid cutoff after $Q=l$” used in the definition of a partial sum.)  So instead of using a suitable fancy summation, we may just
correct every sum (in $P$) over a particular $Q$ by $±t·φ(Q)/Q$.  (After this correction, this sum in $P$ becomes 1-periodic in $t$.)

To “show” that such correction has the same effect as “a regularized summation”, it is enough to show that a *suitable* regularized
sum of the coefficients $±t·φ(Q)/Q$ at $t$ vanishes.  So let us *define* this sum via an analytic continuation (as above) by replacing $Q$
in the denominator by $Q^s$; then we need to show that the value at $s=1$ vanishes.  Using Euler products, one gets:
$$   ∑_Q ℒ(Q,c)φ(Q)/Q^s = ∏_p (1/p + (1-1/p)/(1-ℒ(p \operatorname{mod}c)/p^{s-1})) = Φ(s-1)/Φ(s)\\
\text{ with }Φ(s) ≔ 1/∏_p(1-ℒ(p \operatorname{mod}c)/p^s) = ∑_nℒ(n \operatorname{mod}c)/n^s. $$
The manipulations make perfect sense for $\operatorname{Re}s>2$, when the convergence is absolute.  Moreover, $Φ(s)$ converges for $\operatorname{Re}s>0$ with $Φ(1)≠0$;
hence if we can show that $\lim_{s→1+} Φ(s-1)=0$ this implies $Φ(s-1)/Φ(s) → 0$ when $s→1+$.

Indeed, $∑_{k=-v}^v ℒ(k \operatorname{mod}c)=0$; moreover, $∑_{k=-v}^v kℒ(k \operatorname{mod}c)=0$ since $c≡₄1$ (so $ℒ(k \operatorname{mod}c)$ is even in $k$); here $|c|=2v+1$.  These sums appear
when one plugs Taylor expansion in $k$ of $1/n^s$ with $n=cm+k$ into $Φ(s) = ∑_nℒ(n \operatorname{mod}c)/n^s$:
$$     ∑_m∑_kℒ(k \operatorname{mod}c)·(1/(cm)^s - sk/(cm)^{s+1} + ℛ(m,k,s)).   $$
Hence two first terms of the Taylor expansion $1/(cm)^s$ and $-sk/(cm)^{s+1}$ contribute 0 into this sum (when $m≥1$).  What remains is the
$n$⸣s not covered by our substitution $n=cm+k$ (so $1≤n≤v$), which sum to $½∑_{k=-v}^v ℒ(k \operatorname{mod}c)=0$ when $s=0$, and the remainders $ℛ(m,k,s)$ in the
Taylor series which are $s(s+1)k²ℒ(n \operatorname{mod}c)/2(cm+Δ_{k,m})^{s+2}$ (with $|Δ_{k,m}|<v$).  The only things about remainders important to us are
the absolute convergence (for $\operatorname{Re}s>-1$, which covers a neighborhood of $s=0$), and the factor $s$ which shows that the value at $s=0$
vanishes.